# Correct MIME Type for css.map files

Tags: python, http, amazon-s3, mime-types, boto3

looking for a bit of help that will most likely help other devs.

When serving files that are extension `.css.map` what should their MIME type be?

This problem arose for me when serving files from s3 and in the upload process using boto3, one must set the MIME type for each files using the Python [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html) library. However `mimetypes` does not have all newer standards (i.e. '.scss', '.svg', '.js.map'). With that what is the appropriate MIME type for `.css.map` files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.css.map` files should be `application/json`

As an educated guess, I will say that `.css.map` files MIME type should be `application/json` as determined from the `.css.map` and `.js.map` files being returned when navigating to http://getbootstrap.com/

The file is being served from http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/docs.min.css.map

Answer (score -1):

Question was asked a long time ago, but I was looking for the answer and discovered it should be

```
Content-type: application/octet-stream
```

I honestly just used curl to grab it from `https://petstore.swagger.io/swagger-ui.css.map`